# Chrome extension is not reading my API's image value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a project using the Weather API:

https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=...&q=California

If you guys go to that link, you will see there is an option for an icon 
something like this:

```
"icon: "//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png"
```

I used this project to create a chrome extension but the icon for the weather does not show up in my chrome extension.

Anyone know what I need to add to my chrome extension?

Comment: read about CORB

Comment: @Sergej I see `access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: @Michael. Add https: to the icon. Your page is likely not https

Comment: `$("#someContainer").html(\`<img src="https:${data.current.condition.icon}" />\`)`

Comment: http is also working for this specific API

Comment: Then he is using a local file with `file:` protocol

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks so much! Im kind of confused because im new to this whole Chrome Extension process. Why does my image 'src' attribute need an HTTPS before the file name? Thanks again!

Comment: Because `//` means that the icon src will change protocol to whatever the calling page's protocol is. So on an http page, it will load from `http://cdn.apixu.com` and if your page is https, the icon will load from `https://cdn.apixu.com` but if your page comes from file system, then `file:///cdn.apixu.com` will fail to load

Comment: Oh kk, Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because // means that the icon src will change protocol to whatever the calling page's protocol is. So on an
**http** page, it will load from `http://cdn.apixu.com` and if your page is
**https**, the icon will load from `https://cdn.apixu.com` but if your page comes from file system, then the protocol is
**file** and will result in `file:///cdn.apixu.com`, which will fail to load

Try

```
$("#someContainer").html(`<img src="https:${data.current.condition.icon}" />`)
```

assuming you use jQuery